# Why is setting scheduler handlers to null after tests necessary?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

When testing RxJava code, we do this:

```
  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
  }
```

to have everything running on the main thread.

I see people do this:

```
  @After
  fun tearDown() {
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { null }
  }
```

Is this necessary and if yes, why?

Comment: If you need real concurrency with the real schedulers in som tests then yes, undo all plugin changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what setting null does here, but I think it's better to abstract these details and simply call `RxJavaPlugin.reset() I suppose`and personally I think this is just good practise. The plugins are global and you don't know if another test requires some other scheduler setup.

Comment: @Fred Ah, so these aren't reset for each test class? Then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: that's what I understood :) @akarnokd can most likely explain this in detail